# Eclipse can't import vitamio

Tags: android, vitamio

I can't import vitamio to eclipse, this is what appears
[image]

[image]

What is the problem ? I downloaded the vitamio bundle from [here](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Vitamio folder inside the VitamioBundle-master folder in Eclipse to import. It should work there. Reason is that the VitamioBundle folder isn't a importable Android project. Take a look at a manual project. It has AndroidManifest.xml, the assets folder, bin folder, gen folder, and more. Now look at the VitamioBundle folder. It doesn't have any of that, cause it's not an importable project.

Comment: sorry, the bin folder is loaded on a good run, it's composed of the inside stuff, don't worry about it. i have already ran the project that i looked at. don't double click the vitamio folder in eclipse, **select** it and hit ok, import, whatever.

Comment: i don't have a linux os (is that linux?)

Comment: It's a mac os... But I can't import it.. finish button is unable

Comment: is it a project or library? it's starting to display Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

Comment: yes.. how to do that ? I don't know much of stackoverflow

Comment: nvm can't do a new chat room, need 100 rep. **IS VITAMIO MEANT TO BE A PROJECT OR LIBRARY?**

Comment: I want vitamio do be a library so i can include it on my app to play some videos...

Comment: Go to https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/v3.0, download the .zip, and extract. Go into folder. Should be a res folder, in it, there's vitamio.jar. Remember the path. Go into Eclipse, select the project you want vitamio to be in, right click, properties. Click Java Build Path, click Libraries if not already in it, click Add External JARs, go to res folder in Eclipse, select vitamio.jar, and voila!

Comment: Very good explanation ;) today i'm going to try that and give you a feedback. Thanks a lot

Comment: Noo :( i was able to load the vitamio jar but i can't load the init class

Comment: I don't know anything about Vitamio or the init class, so I can't help you anymore. Sorry!